# Mongo - Find is returning differents results with each request

Tags: mongodb, sharding, pagination

Currently in my collection has the following spec:

- Version: MongoDb - 4.0.6
- Sharding: 3 shards
- Shard key: Publication identifier
- The shards are consistent

The problem is due using the same operation find is returning three types of results with each find.

```
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(3)
```

Example:

```
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(10)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b804a04bf7c61ab9ce85a2"), "name" : "db7e50d9" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b805a44bf7c61ad5cfbbc9"), "name" : "8dfe6ba9" } // SET TYPE 1
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b8081d4bf7c61ae3d2e215"), "name" : "0552ffdc" }
...
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(10)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b7d2164bf7c6346c4abad1"), "name" : "495f87f5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b8062e4bf7c61ad5d06cef"), "name" : "b61d2d6b" }  // SET TYPE 2
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b807ee4bf7c61ab9d2b159"), "name" : "8e8c9bb0" }
...
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(10)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b804a04bf7c61ab9ce85a2"), "name" : "db7e50d9" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b805a44bf7c61ad5cfbbc9"), "name" : "8dfe6ba9" }  // SET TYPE 1
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b8081d4bf7c61ae3d2e215"), "name" : "0552ffdc" }
...
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(10)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b804a04bf7c61ab9ce85a2"), "name" : "db7e50d9" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b805a44bf7c61ad5cfbbc9"), "name" : "8dfe6ba9" }  // SET TYPE 1
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b8081d4bf7c61ae3d2e215"), "name" : "0552ffdc" }
...
mongos> db.publications.find({"tag":"university"},{"name":1}).skip(0).limit(10)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b7d2164bf7c6346c4abad1"), "name" : "013d86af" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b8062e4bf7c61ad5d06cef"), "name" : "ab267d90" }  // SET TYPE 3
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b807ee4bf7c61ab9d2b159"), "name" : "f27f9a10" }
```

The find is returning three set different with the same find, the problem is:

- It is returning different 3 types of results on the first page.
- **I can't use the option sort** (takes more of 70 seconds in order the publications. More 2B results)

I think that this behavior is due to sharding.

Do you know any way to solve it or return the same results without sort operation?

Comment: SInce your query does not include the shard key it will be a "scatter gather query" that needs to merge results from all shards. If you want query results returned in a predictable order you need to provide a sort key (which is the case with or without sharding). Otherwise query results are returned in an undefined "as they are found" natural ordering which does not make sense for pagination. Is your 70 seconds for sort an in-memory sort or using an index? The ideal outcome would be [using an index to sort query results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

Comment: For your reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105009/implementing-pagination-in-mongodb , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599069/how-does-mongodb-sort-records-when-no-sort-order-is-specified